# Uncertainty Estimation with Bayesian Inference

Tags: probabilistic-programming, pymc3

I am modeling a generalized extreme value distribution with the code below in PYMC3. I have defined my own distribution as the gev is still not available in pymc3. The function defined is the PDF of extreme value distribution. The priors are taken from the recommendations in the chapter 9 of the book "An Introduction to the Statistical Modelling of the extreme values"(2001) by Stuart Cole.With this prior setting, i am getting a lot of divergences which were corrected by setting target_accept=0.99.  Now I want to perform prior predictive checks. I tried to do so as recommended in various tutorials with the in-built Pymc3 function but it keeps on giving me Key errors. Here is the posterior trace of the parameters.[image]  The aim of the posterior analysis is to compare the theoretical distribution (MLE) with the distribution obtained from parameters using Bayesian inference. The code is attached below.
Many thanks

```
def gev_logp(value, loca, sig, xi):
scaled = (value - loca) / sig
logp_xi_not_zero = -(tt.log(sig)
         + ((xi + 1) / xi) * tt.log1p(xi * scaled)
         + (1 + xi * scaled) ** (-1/xi))
logp_xi_zero = -tt.log(sig) + (xi+1)*(-(value - loca)/sig) - tt.exp(-(value - loca)/sig)
logp = tt.switch(tt.abs_(xi) > 1e-4, logp_xi_not_zero, logp_xi_zero)
return tt.sum(logp)

with pm.Model() as model_gev:
loca = pm.Normal('loca', mu=5, sigma=20)
sig= pm.Normal('sig',mu=2, sigma=15)
xi = pm.Normal('xi', mu=0, sigma=0.1)


gev = pm.DensityDist('gev', gev_logp, observed = {'value':datin.data1,     'loca':local,'sig':sig, 'xi':xi})
trace = pm.sample(7000, cores=4, chains=4, tune=2500, return_inferencedata=True,    idata_kwargs={"density_dist_obs": False}, target_accept=0.99[![enter image description here][1]][1])
```

Comment: It is not appropriate to build priors based on MLEs **from the same data**.

Comment: Hi Frank, Could you please elaborate. The intended application is in risk-based decision-making and was recommended by an expert.

Comment: Simply put you are double dipping.  In a Bayesian model the prior encodes information that is _outside_ of the sample.  Your approach will result in a very, very large amount of false confidence (posterior distributions too narrow).  You are essentially doubling your sample size without sampling new observations.  Have you studied the methods behind the software?

Comment: @Dawar I agree with Frank Harrell.  If you build the prior on MLE, then the posterior is unlikely to be substantially different from the MLE (it would be just the MLE with each observation duplicated?)

Comment: @FrankHarrell and Dikran Thanks for pointing this out. I have just started reading the conceptual introduction to HMC by Betancourt. The question of prior choice was always bothering me. Initially, I set the sd to be large to account for prior ignorance, but it was giving me huge number of divergences. So, after several model runs, they recommended me to reduce the standard deviation and take the MLE values which seemed to work as is evident in the trace plot.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial The question is updated now. With this prior choice, I am getting values close to MLE, just the shape parameter is positive. Here are the values with MLE: shape = -0.07499, loca= 14.72807, scale= 5.386821 and with Bayesian loca = 14.85, sig=5.81, xi=0.04.

Comment: That prior choice is INVALID.   You are double dipping.   Don't let convergence make you think something is working correctly.   Use well thought out priors that capture what is known about the problem and don't use current data.   This will ordinarily lead you to non-flat priors.

Comment: @FrankHarrell The choice of priors is now taken from 2 papers and exactly as suggested by Coles for this particular problem. I don't understand how am I double-dipping here?

Comment: You said the prior was from the MLE.  I assumed that it was the MLE computed on the same data now being analyzed.  Did I misinterpret?  Technical point: priors don't come from MLEs; they come from entire posterior distributions of previous analyses.

Comment: Wouldn't you only use an old posterior as a prior if you thought your current data are exchangeable with the old data?

Comment: @FrankHarrell I do agree that initially, I looked at the MLE and built my priors based on that. However, as I gained more knowledge about priors, I have corrected it and chose weakly informative priors with a large variance as suggested by Coles in "An Introduction to the Statistical Modelling of the extreme values"(2001) and many other papers. In fact, for the shape parameter, I also tried a Beta prior. However, the shape parameter is inferred positive which reflects in the return level estimates with large uncertainty.

Comment: @JTH you are confusing this with hierarchical models, I think.  In general, priors are not dependent on exchangeability of data but rather on pre-existing information about effects (parameter values).

Comment: @FrankHarrell Sorry for the late response. If I am getting it right, in the Bayesian scheme, we can do what is called sequential updating. The posterior that we get after inference can be used as a prior for further analysis.

Comment: Yes.  It's just that you don't need to stop and create a new prior each time.  Just update the data and recompute the current posterior distribution.

Comment: To play devil's advocate, non-Bayesians can update their analyses in light of new data as well. It's probably even easier from a non-bayesian perspective.